# Fill in the blanks with words given within parentheses by applying appropriate tenses

Tags: tense

Fill in the blanks with words given within parentheses by applying appropriate tenses **:**

Yesterday while I _________ (travel) in a bus, I _______ (happen) to see a gentleman whom at first I _______ (think) I ___________ (not see) him before. Then I ________ (realize) that he _________ (be) a friend of mine during my school days.

**My attempt** **:** Yesterday while I **was traveling** in a bus, I **happened** to see a gentleman whom at first I **thought** I **haven't seen** him before. Then I **realized** that he **had been** a friend of mine during my school days.

The only thing which confuses me is the portion... "I thought I **haven't** seen him before." Grammarly app suggests that it should be "I thought I **hadn't** seen him before."

Can anybody please check it?

Comment: FYI, there's actually something amiss in the text itself (nothing to do with your answers): _...whom at first I _______I _______him before_ should read _whom at first I _______I_______before_ (the "him" should come out).

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is correct. There's nothing wrong about it.

Comment: The only thing which confuses me is the portion... "I thought I **haven't** seen him before." Grammarly app suggests that it should be "I thought I **hadn't** seen him before."

Comment: It's odd that "him" is in the sentence. Without it, you have _I happened to see a gentleman whom at first I thought I hadn't seen before_. This works very nicely. If you leave "him" in, you need to add "about": _I happened to see a gentleman about whom at first I thought, "I haven't seen him before"._ This is a bit unwieldy.